# Manually conduct leave-one-out cross validation for a GLMM using a for() loop in R

Tags: r

I am trying to build a for() loop to manually conduct leave-one-out cross validations for a GLMM fit using the lmer() function from the lme4 pkg.  I need to remove an individual, fit the model and use the beta coefficients to predict a response for the individual that was withheld, and repeat the process for all individuals.

I have created some test data to tackle the first step of simply leaving an individual out, fitting the model and repeating for all individuals in a for() loop.

The data have a binary (0,1) Response, an IndID that classifies 4 individuals, a Time variable, and a Binary variable.  There are N=100 observations.  The IndID is fit as a random effect.

```
require(lme4)

#Make data
Response <- round(runif(100, 0, 1))
IndID <- as.character(rep(c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"),25))
Time <- round(runif(100, 2,50))
Binary <- round(runif(100, 0, 1))

#Make data.frame
Data <- data.frame(Response, IndID, Time, Binary)
Data <- Data[with(Data, order(IndID)), ]   #**Edit**: Added code to sort by IndID

#Look at head()
head(Data)
 Response IndID Time Binary
1        0   AAA   31      1
2        1   BBB   34      1
3        1   CCC    6      1
4        0   DDD   48      1
5        1   AAA   36      1
6        0   BBB   46      1

#Build model with all IndID's
fit <- lmer(Response ~ Time + Binary + (1|IndID ), data = Data, 
        family=binomial)
summary(fit)
```

As stated above, my hope is to get four model fits – one with each IndID left out in a `for()` loop.  This is a new type of application of the `for()` command for me and I quickly reached my coding abilities.  My attempt is below.

```
fit <- list()
for (i in Data$IndID){
    fit[[i]] <- lmer(Response ~ Time + Binary + (1|IndID), data = Data[-i], 
        family=binomial)
    }
```

I am not sure storing the model fits as a list is the best option, but I had seen it on a few other help pages. The above attempt results in the error:

```
Error in -i : invalid argument to unary operator
```

If I remove the [-i] conditional to the data=Data argument the code runs four fits, but data for each individual is not removed.

Just as an FYI, I will need to further expand the loop to:
1) extract the beta coefs, 2) apply them to the X matrix of the individual that was withheld and lastly, 3) compare the predicted values (after a logit transformation) to the observed values.  As all steps are needed for each IndID, I hope to build them into the loop. I am providing the extra details in case my planned future steps inform the more intimidate question of leave-one-out model fits.

Thanks as always!

Comment: Are you getting errors?  Are you concerned about the list structure specifically?

Comment: I added some detail above to address your question.  Yes, I am getting errors.  I am not too concerned with the list.  I am more about getting the proper number of fit with respective data removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is because `Data[-i]` is expecting `i` to be an integer index.  Instead, `i` is either `AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC` or `DDD`.  To fix the loop, set

```
data = Data[Data$IndID != i, ]
```

in you model fit.

Comment: I would also suggest, just for readability, `fit0 <- lmer(...)`; `lapply(Data$IndID,function(i) update(fit,data=subset(Data,IndID!=i)))`

Comment: Thanks @Christopher for the helpful response.  I was also toying with using for (i in unique(Data$IndID)){ it the beginning of the for loop to specify the unique IndID.  This runs a bit faster, but I was not sure if that was OK to include in the set up of a for() loop.

Comment: Actually, `(i in unique(Data$IndID))` is correct each subject has multiple rows.  Somehow I missed that when I looked at your data.

Comment: you may also want to check out the `influence.ME` package, which does something along these lines ...